# bufferedreader search text file?

Tags: java

file txt:

> 1 aaa 100

where insert number 1 the output null

java :

```
private static void SearchForId() {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Inter Id");
            String id = scanner.next();
            BufferedReader Buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                    "D://Save.txt")));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = Buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.trim().equals(id)) {
                    System.out.println(line + "\n");

                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("" + e);
        }

    }
```

where the problem.??

Comment: What's going wrong and what do you want it to do?

Comment: Find the number in the file

Comment: Why are you calling `println()` with an additional newline? The point of it is being printLINE - it already adds one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
    private static void SearchForId() {
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Inter Id");
        String id = scanner.next();
        BufferedReader Buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                "D://Save.txt")));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = Buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            String arr[] = line.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i].trim().equals(id)) {
                    System.out.println(line);

                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("" + e);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question correctly, you don't need `Scanner` here:

```
private static void SearchForId() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Inter Id");
        BufferedReader Buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                "D://Save.txt")));
        String[] line = Buffer.readLine().split(" ");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
        String s = line[1];
        int b = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("" + e);
    }

}
```

Comment: How exactly is this supposed to compile without a declaration for `scanner`? And how exactly does it search the file when it only reads one line?  And how can you use `readLine()` without checking the result for null? or `split()` without checking the length of the array returned?

Comment: @EJP file.txt in the question contains exactly one line and exactly 3 numbers, so checking for `null` is useless here.

Comment: You don't understand the question at all, let alone correctly. The OP has written a loop. He is trying to scan a file. Your code reads one line and assigns to two otherwise unused variables. It doesn't ask the user for an ID. It doesn't print a result. It is completely and utterly irrelevant to the question.